# Why does my clarinet play a "Bb" when the music shows a "C" and I finger for a "C"?

Tags: sheet-music, fingering, clarinet

I am trying to learn to play the clarinet and was doing fairly well until I tried to play a tune with my granddaughters on flute and piano.  My clarinet was not in tune with their instruments.  I have a "Teach yourself" type of book that includes fingering.  When the music indicates a "C" and I set my fingers to what the book says is a "C" it actually plays a "Bb".  Why doesn't the music show a "Bb" for that fingering?  Do I need to transpose all my music to enable me to play with other people on other instruments?  Why did my book tell me that a certain fingering plays a "C" when it actually plays a "Bb"?

Comment: You may start with [this question](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/5374/2600) and its answer to learning about transposing instruments.

Comment: If you teach yourself book about clarinet doesn't mention it's a _transposing_ instrument, get another book. It may take some time to wrap your head around the concept, but a descent book about clarinet definitely needs to explain it.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure this is a dupe, but - the clarinet, like several other instruments, is a **transposing** instrument. Yours makes the sound a whole tone lower than the music says. So when you see and play a C note, a B♭ comes out. There are other clarinets, but the 'B♭' is the most common.

You'll have to either learn to play by transposing *up* a tone from your music, (like I did with trumpet - a similar idea), or get the piano music transposed *down* a tone, either physically, with a good reader - or, these days, by hitting the transpose button on the keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is about professional play of similar instruments of different sizes (and therefore pitches).

Think of "C" as a finger position: you read a C, you put your fingers in that position.  If you pick up a B-flat instrument or whatever, then the same finger position will play a B-flat.

It's up to the COMPOSER to figure out the right transpositions, so you don't have to transpose in your head while you're playing your part from sheet music.  I mean, some pieces even have multiple instruments played by the same person!

Comment: In fact, this is the *whole* motivation for having transposing instruments at all. The entire business of notating X as Y would be totally pointless if there weren't a large number of people who routinely play different instruments of the same class and can profit from it.

Comment: This starts out on the right track and then gets lost, failing to explain anything relevant. For one thing, there are Bb, C, Eb, and A clarinets (and I think a rare D as well)

Comment: I'm not sure what the disconnect is for you.  Maybe you can explain what you think I neglected to mention?